# OpenGL Rendering issue on Samsung Devices

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I have an application drawing some objects with OpenG-ES 2.0.The application fails to render on some of samsung devices. I tried debugging and it seems to be problem with the vertex and fragment shaders.

Here is my shader code:
Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec3 Position; 
attribute vec4 SourceColor; 

varying vec4 DestinationColor; 

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;
uniform mat4 CordTransform;
attribute float flag;
attribute float clubColorFlag;

attribute vec2 TexCoordIn; // New
varying vec2 TexCoordOut; // New
varying float flagS;
varying float flagClubColorS;
void main(void) {   
        gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * vec4(Position,1.0);  
        flagS = flag;  
        flagClubColorS = clubColorFlag;  
        if (clubColorFlag == 1.0) {  
            DestinationColor = vec4(0.190,0.309,0.309,1.0);  
        }  
        else {   
            DestinationColor = SourceColor;  
        }  
        exCoordOut = TexCoordIn;  
        gl_PointSize = 1.0;  
    }
```

Fragment Shader:

```
varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;

varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut; // New
uniform sampler2D Texture; // New
varying lowp float flagS;
varying lowp float flagClubColorS;
void main(void) {

    gl_FragColor = DestinationColor;
    if(flagS == 1.0){
        gl_FragColor = DestinationColor;
    }
    else if (flagClubColorS == 1.0) {
        gl_FragColor = DestinationColor;
    }
    else if (flagS == 0.0){
        gl_FragColor = DestinationColor * texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut); // New
    }
}
```

I am not sure what is the problem but I get texture uniform -1 if I comment out the if-else part in fragment shader. In other scenario, it is zero. Both shaders compile without any errors.
Is it related to precision? Please help me to debug the issue.

Comment: *I get texture uniform -1* Are you sure this is your problem? If you don't use a uniform in a shader (it is commented out), then it is legal for the compiler to get rid of it. Your uniform returns -1 because it is not used anywhere.

Comment: I had commented out that code while debugging. Even with that code UN-commented, rendering on device fails. In such case texture uniform is 0.

Comment: 0 is a legal value for a uniform, there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am answering my own question for people who are going to refer this later. I could kind of solve the issue.

The problem was not in either of the shaders. The issue was, I was using `glDrawElements()` method to draw objects with vertex and index buffers. I replaced this call with `glDrawArrays()` method using only vertex buffer and everything worked fine.

I am still not sure of the exact issue but it may help somebody struggling long for similar issue.